# Making AJAX call on successful validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an HTML form that I validate using the [ketchup plugin](http://usejquery.com/posts/jquery-ketchup-plugin-tasty-form-validation) I declare my form with the following tag:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="#">
```

On successful validation, I call a function that makes an AJAX call:

```
function test(func){
    if (func == "change") {
        t = json_change(jdata, 0, '', '', '', qsParm['index']);
    }   
    else if  (func == "restore") {
        t = jdata
    }

    var json_data = {d: JSON.stringify(t)} 
    $.post('/submit',json_data, function(data) {
        document.write(data)
    });
}
```

My problem is that if I make any changes to the input fields and then submit it works ok, but if I simply click on submit without making any changes to my fields, I get an error:

> NotFound: (404, "The path '/index_edit.html' was not found.")

the name of my webpage is index_edit.html

Comment: Can you please post your complete code. including /index_edit.html line.

Comment: Which line causes the error ? can you post that ?

Comment: well..sorry about one piece of info...turns out, its not even working when I change the input value...Strangely enough, this code works sometimes ....thats what confusing me...
 and Actually I am not calling the page index_edit any where. My guess is, since I have placed nothing in the forms' action attribute, it tries to go to the current page 'index_edit.html'..but since in cherrypy, you have to explicitly define all your possible 'paths',and map those paths to functions in the server(for example '/submit' in my test function calls a function in server called 'submit()',

Comment: also, forgive me if the above reasoning for error is too stupid as I am quite new to JS. Lastly, if I remove the ajax call in my test() function, it is working fine...so I guess my question should be HOW TO MAKE AN AJAX CALL HERE?